# What are eCPM and eCPC?

Tags: admob, iad, ads

Can someone explain me, in brief and easy way, what are eCPM and eCPC that I see in iAD, adMob, ecc. advertising sites?

There are lot of sites that talk about this but they all give long and complicated explanation...

Answer (score -1):

- eCPM == Earnings per (Mille) thousand impressions
- eCPC == Earnings per Click